# Webkit browsers froze while loading some pages

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, firefox, opera, webkit

Some pages will just lag whole browser so it's impossible to work with it. It will just stop working. I've tried uninstalling, clearing all cache, cookies almost everything, even browser folders, disabling extensions, reseting settings to defaults, I've really tried a lot. But nothing works for me. It's no all the sites which will lag the browser, but I've found out that this site ( http://clickandstudy.com/DebilniKecyStudentu ) every time I try to load it it just lag the browser for about 30 seconds and I'm unable to do anything (I can just kill it through the task manager). There is a lot of sites which will lag it, but a lot of sites will not. I'm using Kaspersky Internet Security 2015, I've done full scan - no virus. I've checked installed programs - no suspicious. I've tried it using Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari, IE. Firefox and IE worked fine for me, Opera, Safari and chrome therefore webkit browsers will stuck but Firefox and IE not.

Does anyone have the same problem? I really don't know what should I do cause I don't want reinstall whole system right now.

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: http://clickandstudy.com/DebilniKecyStudentu -> "Page not found"

Comment: @DavidPostill It doesn't matter that, page on that page is not found, what matter is that I cannot even open this page (website), my webkit browser will just freeze o.O

Comment: It does matter. You need to give working pages if you ask "Does anyone have the same problem?". How can we test with non working pages?

Comment: @DavidPostill But the page is working, the fact that it is an error page doesn't matter it's a page (article). I cannot load this link, if I do, my webkit browsers will just stuck and I need to restart them or wait for about a minute.

Comment: Shrug. Latest Chrome gives me page not found in a few seconds ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I've found out, that it was by KAV 2015. I've uninstalled it and it works just fine o.O Why do I even buy such a things like Antivirus? o.O Everything is slow after it o.O

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm waiting for answer from Kaspersky forum. Then I'll write it also with solution, maybe there is someone who is having the same problem  :)

Answer (score 0):

It was cause I let the Kaspersky Internet Security 15 installer upgrade the old Kaspersky Internet Security 14 version. You have to uninstall old version first. And you need to have 2015 15.0.1.415 MR1 version.

[There is a tutorial for upgrade KIS14 to KIS15](http://forum.kaspersky.com/index.php?showtopic=67812)

This solution seems to be working for me.